# AngularJS, after upgrading from 1.1.5 to 1.2.2, filter issue

Tags: angularjs, filter, jsfiddle

Just recently upgraded my app from ng 1.1.5 to 1.2.2 .
The structure for the part with the issue is,

1. a sort of form to add privileges. This form is also used for filtering the list below.
2. an ng-repeat list to list the privileges defined.

It used to work as described, but changed its behaviour after 1.2.2, now the listing comes empty, after i change the select options then based on the selected items, filter kicks in and shows only the filtered rows.

So, just couldn't find a way to implement my original design with 1.2.2.

Here are the fiddles for both working and non-working versions, the code in both versions is identical, the only difference is version of the AngularJS library:

> 1.1.5 (working): http://jsfiddle.net/yasarbayar/5zkH4/
>
> 1.2.2 (not-working): http://jsfiddle.net/yasarbayar/h4vYL/

I have to put some code for jsfiddle links to get kicked in, so a portion of the code from jsfiddle is:

```
$scope.model = {
    level_id: null,
    type: null,
    topic_id: null,
    access: null,
    create: null,
    read: null,
    update: null,
    delete: null
};

$scope.access = {...};
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a [bug report](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5117) on angularjs github, and seems like the filterFilter function is changed. So,

> if you want to match anything then you now need to set the filter property to undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems are related to your filters. And let me tell you, those are some seriously hairy filters.

I don't know that this will actually fix the problem, but I'd suggest writing a custom filter for this application.