# $rootScope variable value not upating in Angular filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

we're currently upgrading from Angular 1.2X to 1.4X and are experiencing a weird behavior change in terms of using filters.

I've made an example on plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/iVABuG5ApiwgyV6RRwQA?p=preview

```
  .filter('convert', function($rootScope) {
    return function(input) {
      var out = parseInt(input) * $rootScope.convert_rate;
      return out;
    };
  })
```

Basically, we're taking a value (e.g. 5) and multiplying it by a conversion rate, via a filter. The conversion rate is specified in a $rootScope variable.

In Angular 1.2X (check that Angular 1.2x is defined in index.html), the filter runs and the value updates when you change the conversion rate.

In Angular 1.5 beta, when the conversion rate is changed, the filter does not run and the value does not update.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: i think it is because of changes in filter functionality. i found one answere http://stackoverflow.com/a/20203059/4944490 you can visit this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because angular instance $filter just once, so your $rootScope in your filter will be old. The best way is just pass your convert_rate as argument to your filter.

See this plunker i've made for you http://plnkr.co/edit/yNea42CeBBG2KNEmugku?p=preview

```
//In your filter
.filter('convert', function() {
return function(input, convert_rate) {
  console.log(input);
  var out = parseInt(input) * convert_rate;
  return out;
};
})

//Your HTML

{{original_value | convert: convert_rate}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Angular (1.4 or 1.5, i can't say), when you modify a value in `$rootScope`, Angular don't trigger the digest cycle. So you have to call it yourself :

```
$rootScope.convert_rate = new_value;
$rootScope.$apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass convert_rate in filter parameter, everything will remain same.

```
Value: {{original_value | convert:convert_rate}}<br> 
filter('convert', function($rootScope) {
    return function(input,convert_rate) {
      var out = parseInt(input) * convert_rate;
      return out;
    };
  })
```

here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GQyJiHymdZYT0CxlQ7sQ?p=preview)